# Disable further listbox input after subroutine is called in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

> Here is my subroutine which is called by double clicking text in the listbox "LstAnswer4"
> I have 4 listboxes on the form and want to disable any further inputs after double clicking one of them.

```
    Public Sub LstAnswer4_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lstAnswer4.MouseDoubleClick
    If res4 = 2 Then
        MsgBox("correct")
        Score = Score + 1
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Dim displayscore As Object
        displayscore = (Score & " out of " & outof)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(displayscore)
    Else MsgBox("wrong")
    End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: You can just disable the listboxes with something like _ListBox1.Enabled = False_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can disable the listboxes like so:

```
Listbox1.Enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to disable all 4(+) of the listboxes there's a few ways to approach this.

If you want to disable *all* of the listboxes on the form you can do that this way by disabling all of the form's controls that are of type listbox:

```
    For Each Contr As Control In Me.Controls
        If Contr.GetType() = GetType(ListBox) Then
            Contr.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

If there's listboxes on the form you don't want to disable but the ones you do are similarly named (ex: LstAnswer**x**) you can use a wildcard/StartsWith to match the beginning of the control's name:

```
    For Each Contr As Control In Me.Controls
        If Contr.GetType() = GetType(ListBox) And Contr.Name.StartsWith("LstAnswer") Then
            Contr.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```